# Quantitative aspect of Caratheodory theorem

Tags: convex-analysis

Let  A  be a compact convex set in  n-dimensional space.
[ Of principal interest is n > 2 . ]

A result of Caratheodory states that  A  is equal to the
union of its simplices  (i.e. simplices with all  (n+1)
vertices lying in  A ).

Suppose further that each of these simplices has volume
bounded above by one .

Does this yield an upper bound for the volume of A itself?

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, if you put your comment under the answer instead of the question, then the answerer will be notified of it (and it will be easier for readers to understand what you're referring to).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude but easy bound.  Let $\triangle$ be a regular simplex of volume one centred at the origin; WLOG, $\triangle$ is the largest volume simplex contained in $A$.  Then $A\subseteq -n\triangle$, so $\operatorname{vol}(A)\le n^n$.

(If $A$ is the Euclidean ball circumscribed around $\triangle$, it satisfies your condition, and $\operatorname{vol}(A)$ is like $(cn)^{n/2}$.)